# i want to send value form one jsp to another jsp page by using link href but i got error

Tags: jsp

index.jsp  ">click

common.jsp String attr= request.getAttribute("param");
out.print(attr);%>`

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object 
 to String`
```

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow, try giving more informations, code and solutions that you already tried, this way you help other users to find a solution for you, also, see how to ask a good question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The getAttribute  method returns a  java.lang.Object .  You need to cast to String   like this,   String attr  =  (String)request.getAttribute("param");

Comment: But, if you are doing what you stated in  your question  title, then you should use  the 
 getParameter method.